# Erro ao abrir form dentro do panel

Tags: vb.net

Eu gostaria de abrir um form dentro de um panel, mas quando ele abre, ele fica sempre do mesmo tamanho e no mesmo lugar independente do tamanho dor form ou da localização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Dim rv As New formRV

        rv.link = lvPasta.SelectedItems(0).ImageKey
        rv.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        rv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        rv.TopLevel = False


        Dim p As New Panel
        With p
            Size = New Size(Me.Width, Me.Height)
            Location = New Point(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y)
        End With


        Me.Controls.Add(p)
        p.BringToFront()

        p.Controls.Add(rv)

        p.Show()
        rv.Show()
```

**Edit:**

Alem do `panel` eu tentei apenas criar o novo form e exibi-lo, escondendo o form antigo, mas eu tive o problema da tela "piscar" enquanto o form troca (form principal some - pedaço do windows - novo form aparece) e os botões para que quando o novo form fosse fechado pelo "X" (onde normalmente fecha um programa) o primeiro form fosse fechado, mas quando clicasse em um outro botão para "voltar" ele fechasse o form2 mas não o primeiro form.

```
Dim rv As New formRodaVideo

        rv.linkvideo = lvPasta.SelectedItems(0).ImageKey
        rv.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
        rv.TopLevel = True
        rv.Width = Me.Width
        rv.Height = Me.Height
        rv.Location = Me.Location
        rv.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        rv.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultBounds

        rv.Show()
        Me.Hide()
```

Comment: Olá @Lucas. Qual a sua ideia com isso? O que pretende fazer?

Comment: Eu tenho o form principal e quando eu aperto um botão nele, eu preciso chamar um segundo form, de forma que, o segundo form, seja aberto no mesmo local com o mesmo tamanho que o primeiro form e mantendo o primeiro form escondido ate que o segundo form seja fechado. E logo após que o segundo form seja fechado eu precisaria que o primeiro form fosse aberto no mesmo lugar do segundo form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, pela imagem que colocou, parece que os `Form` estão num `MdiContainer`, onde o código abaixo pode ajudá-lo a atingir o que pretende:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form1 = Me.MdiChildren().Where(Function(r) r.Name = "Form1").FirstOrDefault()

    If Not form1 Is Nothing Then
        form1.Hide()

        Dim form2 As Form1 = New Form1

        AddHandler form2.FormClosed, AddressOf form2_FormClosed

        With form2
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            .Text = "Form2"
            .MdiParent = form1.MdiParent
            .Size = form1.Size
            .Location = form1.Location
            .Show()
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Dim form1 = Me.MdiChildren().Where(Function(r) r.Name = "Form1").FirstOrDefault()
    Dim form2 As Form1 = sender

    If Not form1 Is Nothing Then
        With form1
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            .BringToFront()
            .Location = form2.Location
            .Size = form2.Size
            .Show()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Só precisa adaptar os nomes dos `Form` para o que precisa.

### EDIT

Se os `Form` não são `MdiChild` então pode fazer desta forma (algo parecido com o anterior):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()

        Dim form2 As Form1 = New Form1

        AddHandler form2.FormClosed, AddressOf form2_FormClosed

        With form2
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            .Text = "Form2"
            .Size = Me.Size
            .Location = Me.Location
            .Show()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub form2_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        Dim form2 As Form1 = sender

        With Me
            .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            .BringToFront()
            .Location = form2.Location
            .Size = form2.Size
            .Show()
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Pressupõe a existência de um botão `Button1` no `Form`.

Dessa forma já não tem o "piscar" entre os `Form`, devido à propriedade `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual`, que evita que ao fazer o `Show()` a localização seja reiniciada (penso que a localização também estará relacionada).

Comment: Não é mdi, é um panel que tinha sido criado no código que eu coloquei. Eu estava tentando abrir dentro dele. Eu tentei outra coisa também em vez de abrir no `panel`. Editei a pergunta.